# Video auto play first top item in listview when scroll stops in android

Tags: android, listview, video, autoplay

I wants to play a video in mute mode without any media controller like facebook. I have uses a custom listView, in which i have used VideoView to play video when listview scroll is stopped/idle. But i am not getting proper output as required.

I also tried [this link](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.9ytqyd3xr) but did not get solution.
Thanks if any suggestion/solution. I apologize for my English.

*## **NOTE** All videos are played from network/internet from different URLs.*

Comment: Try using toro video play libary https://github.com/eneim/Toro

Comment: Any other option.Because It causes problem in my code. but run properly when single activity.

Comment: @Test_Me Hi there. I'm Toro's author. Could you describe the problem? It would help me to improve Toro for many other users. Thanks in advance.